# MotionLayout with SwipeRefreshLayout and RecyclerView click issue

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-motionlayout

I have a problem with `RecyclerView` item click after I added `MotionLayout` with `SwipeRefreshLayout`. It seems that `RecyclerView` doesn't catch clicks because of `SwipeRefreshLayout` (without it, it works). Sometimes at click recyclerview scroll to bottom/top uncontrolled. Any idea how to fix it without removing `SwipeRefreshContainer`?

```xml
 <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/layout_description">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filterContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filterContainer">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_large" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/layoutNoResult"
                    layout="@layout/layout_search_view_no_result"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    

implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8"
```

LayoutDescription:

```xml
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="200">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:onTouchUp="stop"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/refreshLayout" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/filterContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/filterContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```